# Website shows index.html as default apache page and other pages are error 500

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, virtualhost, website

I am having issues with apache config, usually its done in minutes but this has me puzzled why it wont work.

I made LetsEncrypt self signed certificates for test use, using presented tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-16-04

Then I created apache config (note, added " to bypass character codes)

<"VirtualHost *:80

```
    ServerName website.org
    ServerAlias www.website.org
    ServerAdmin admin@website.org
    DocumentRoot /var/aegir/hostmaster-7.x-3.11/sites/website.org/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/website.org_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/website.org_access.log combined
```

<"/VirtualHost>

<"VirtualHost *:443>

```
    ServerAdmin admin@website.org
    ServerName  website.org
    DocumentRoot /var/aegir/hostmaster-7.x-3.11/sites/website.org/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/website.org_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/website.org_access.log combined

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/website.org.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/website.org.key

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                   SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

     BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
```

<"/VirtualHost>

Problem is, page without http is opening properly, but on https on index.html im getting default apache page and on every other page that exists Im getting error 500.

What could be causing this issue?

TIA

Comment: What does your apache log files say?

Comment: For now no issues. Just for reference for someone with the similar problem with Aegir and Drupal sites. Sites itself are located in

/var/aegir/hostmaster-7.x-3.11/sites/$YOURWEBSITE/

while drupal instance on aegir is located in 
/var/aegir/hostmaster-7.x-3.11/

so just putting location in that folder worked like a charm. Tnx man, will keep updated if I stumble on more similar errors.